# What sort of analysis is F Jameson's discussion of Hegel?

Tags: hegel

What sort of analysis is F Jameson's discussion of Hegel? Is it right, wrong, unusual? Especially as it appears [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-8705.2008.00839.x/pdf); I'm about to read, and didn't want to cultivate any bad habits, in doing so.

And especially this:

> The categories of Being are those of common sense or a daily life
>   among objects, in which the law of non-contradiction holds sway; this
>   is the world of Verstand or Understanding (in the philosophical jargon
>   of the day), and it will be more thoroughly dealt with in what
>   follows, inasmuch as it is a thought of extension and objectivity, a
>   reified thought which must reify itself in order to grasp its reified
>   objects... Unlike the Faerie Queene, however, if there is a villain,
>   there are no heroes: none of the knights, not the Dialectic, not
>   Reason (Vernunft), not Truth, nor Speculative Thinking, nor even the
>   Notion itself, go forth to do battle with this baleful force (although
>   it might perhaps be argued that Philosophy is itself such a heroic
>   contender, which, besides meaning Hegel, also means all those other
>   positive things).

Comment: What is the "grand scheme of discussion of Hegel"? At a minimum, what you're quoting is most definitely not an orthodox  interpretation of Hegel.

Comment: @virmaior i just mean how it sounds mate, which you've answered, to an extent

Comment: sounds like postmodernism that rejects the success of Hegel's project.

Comment: @virmaior thank you for the two helpful comments. i hope the question gets an answer, tho

Comment: I don't even understand the question...

Comment: @virmaior i don't understand why you think that. you seem to have guessed what the question is i was asking, why do you suppose that you can't be sure?

Comment: @virmaior it's never a good time to be a n00b, even on a question and answer site, evidently, but i'm not trying to use any technical terminology here. so i'm surprised by your apparent confusion

Comment: @MATHEMETICIAN dude tbh you consistently post obscure or unclear stuff regardless of whether anyone is a noob or not

Comment: It's a preamble, and hardly discusses anything but merely sets out some props; I don't see there being much of a question here to answer; it's confusing because it's a decontextualised short extract.

Comment: There's eight missing pages (!) represented by your ...; this is rather a large gap, and not usually how ... is generally used!

Comment: @MoziburUllah ok point taken there, i just don't see where else the question is at all confusing/ed

Answer (score 2):

You need not worry about cultivating bad habits of Hegel interpretation by reading this as long as you read Hegel alongside and don't accept any interpretation that you cannot square with the source.

The opening clause is idiosyncratic.  Hegel says

> Being is the indeterminate immediate; it is free from determinateness
>   in relation to essence and also from any which it can possess within
>   itself. (Science of Logic S. 130)

And it is hard to see that common sense or a daily life among objects would lead us to this claim.

When Jameson says this "will be more thoroughly dealt with in what follows, inasmuch as it is a thought of extension and objectivity..." I guess we can believe that, provisionally.  You must read on and see if Jameson does deal with it that way.

The second half of your quote is simple truth.  Hegel's *Logic* is indeed not like the *Faerie Queene*.  And the history of philosophy shows so many people have argued for so many things that it is surely possible to argue that for Hegel Philosophy is itself a heroic contender.

If I have missed the point of your question, and what you really want to know is what sort of thinker is Fredric Jameson, then I suggest starting with the Wikipedia article on him.